# importing words line by line into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a regular text file containing spellings for my spell checker.

whats is the best way of archiving the following

- It has one word per line
- How can I import this into a database so I could run ssrs reports on 
  it.
- it shouldn't import words that are already in the table.

I'm running sql servr 2005 on my dev box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most data import tasks, I strongly encourage you to use a a staging table.  So, following the following process:

- Create a staging table (it sounds like a table with one column).
- Load data into the staging table (`bulk insert` comes to mind).
- Use this table to load into the final table.
- Delete the staging table.

For the third step:

```
insert into t (word)
    select s.word
    from staging s
    where s.word not in (select t.word from t);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BULK INSERT targettable
    FROM 'C:\path\filename.txt'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )

    SELECT * FROM targettable
```